# vbs script to send data and repeat

Tags: scripting, vbscript

Does anyone have sample VBS code that sends a variable, waits response and repeat?

i have so far:

```
dim input 
input = Inputbox ("Enter Var:" ,"Var sender...") 

SourceURL = "http://example.com/someFunction.php?var="&input&""
```

that's it... my other code is not functional...

thanks in advance, hope anyone can help, totally lost in vbs... in windows in general...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this is Windows Script Host, you can use the [`MSXML2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759148%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) library.

```
do while true

    Dim input, SourceURL 
    input = Inputbox ("Enter Var:" ,"Var sender...") 

    SourceURL = "http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=" & input
    ''// connect and send to server
    Dim http: set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP") 
    http.open "GET", SourceURL, false
    http.send

    if http.status = 200 then
        ''// do something with the return value if necessary 
         WScript.Echo http.responseText
    else
        ''// problem? 
    end if
    ''// pause execution if you don't want to hit the server so often
    WScript.Sleep 10 
loop
```

if you're modifying things on the server, you should probably use a POST request instead of a GET request, but this should work if your server side script only accepts GET requests

Comment: hi, thanks for your response, i think i am getting it, but, how do you make it, to just send the value, then clear the inputbox and await for another response to repeat process indefinitely?

Comment: I've updated the snippet to reflect your comment: I've brought the `inputbox()` inside the loop and the input is now a google query (for my testing). Also I've corrected the `sleep()` call which needs to be a method of the `WScript` object